# Godaddy says name servers are at NameCheap, but NameCheap says domain isn't registered there and DNS can't be edited

Tags: dns, godaddy, namecheap

I am trying to add some DNS record for a domain that is hosted by Godaddy but the DNS info are registered on Namecheap.com (I am not sure why the client has that set up, but that's a different discussion).

I am trying to add a dns record but when i got to GoDaddy the say:
**We can't display your DNS information because your nameservers aren't managed by us.**
[image]

and when I go to Namecheap they say: 
**Unfortunately, you won’t be able to access these features, because this domain is registered with a different registrar.**
[image]

Comment: It sounds like they transfered the domain registrar from NameCheap to GoDaddy but continued to use NameCheap's DNS.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I just need to know how to add the dns record, I was thinking that it should be in nambecheap. but there is nowhere to do it.

Comment: You could start using GoDaddy for DNS hosting.  You'd have to look up the current DNS records and replicate them at Godaddy.  Changing it from custom name servers to GoDaddy name servers.

Comment: If you do a DNS lookup (or examine the WHOIS record) you should be able to clarify who the registrar is and where the NAMESERVERS are pointing? Hhhmm, weird!

Comment: This sounds to me like you registered your domain name with a reseller. There are a quite a few resellers for namecheap. If this is the case, then this is likely where you need to start. Often resellers have tools for you to modify your DNS records which are typically hosted with a larger reseller.

Comment: Provide the domain name involved to get true useful diagnostics and help